# button heights not matching

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am making a website for my college course and I am having problems getting the button heights in my slide show to match up. I was wondering if anyone could give me a clue as to how to get them both to be at the same height?

This is my css for the slide show:

/*=== SLIDESHOW SECTION ===*/

```
#container
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 700px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

}

#container > img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#container > .btn
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    top: 350px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#container>#btn1:hover
{
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px 0px #343d46 ;
}
#container>#btn2:hover
{
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 20px 0px #343d46;
}

#container>#btn2
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;    
}
```

[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9tXs.jpg)

Comment: Clue is in the height.

Comment: I see no buttons me ??

Comment: Add your html snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change your

#container>#btn2
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;    
}  
to  
#container>#btn2
{
    right:0;    
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. U did everything right just that class. Take your time to understand position. I will recommend you visit w3school for further study.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before #container>#btn2:

```
#container>#btn1
{
 position: relative;
 float: left;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning generally shouldn't be applied to classes (multiple elements).

I would remove the absolute positioning on your .btns and use flexbox on your container, like so:-

```
#container
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 700px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex; /* adds flexbox to container */
    align-items: center; /* vertically aligns everything in container */
    justify-content: space-between; /* spaces the buttons as far away `enter code here`from each other as possible */
}
```

You can then add padding to your container for finer adjustments of your buttons horizontal distance from the container edge.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I will research flexboxes. I am very new to HTML, please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: No worries!  We're all new at some point!  Here's a good resource for learning flexbox - https://flexboxfroggy.com/.  Another reason for not using absolute positioning is that it's not great for mobile/responsive design because everything is fixed, whereas with flexbox and other techniques, everything is fluid and responds well to resizing of the page etc.